# How to implement multibleparams like stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to implement a Method with n parameters like

```
[NSString stingWithFormat:(NSString*), ...]
```

I don't know how this "..." is caled in Objective-C in C# i think it's caled "params".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  They are called *variable arguments* (varargs).

[Here's an example](http://www.numbergrinder.com/2008/12/variable-arguments-varargs-in-objective-c/) from the web.